# Rqt dashboard with multiple toolbars

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I'm trying to figure out how to add multiple toolbars in an Rqt dashboard-based plugin. The documentation states that `get_widgets()` returns a list of all the widgets you want to include in your dashboard (quoting [this](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rqt_robot_dashboard/html/classrqt__robot__dashboard_1_1dashboard_1_1Dashboard.html#a3229fa43ecfd5ed7c00867bf088b8140)). Through experimenting I have found that:

- each widgets has to be a part of a sublist of that list
- only a single level of nesting is allowed (for example it's okay to have `[[widget1, widget2], [widget3]]` but not `[[widget1, [widget2, widget3]]]`) so we cannot have subsub...sublists
- each sublist is separated from the others by a separator in the toolbar (really nice feature there :))

So if I have something like

[image: image description]

I would very much like to add multiple such bars. The dashboard gives you 4 toolbar regions (top, bottom, left and right) where you can drag your toolbar. It would be nice to be able to stack multiple toolbars on one side or disperse these along the other regions.

Is this even possible? I'm deriving from the `cob_dashboard` plugin.

Regards,
rbaleksandar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222093/rqt-dashboard-with-multiple-toolbars/) by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2015-12-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The struggle was long and bloody but I managed to find where and how a toolbar can be added. I had to dig through the `cob_dashboard` then through the `rqt_robot_dashboard` followed by a long stare at the `Plugin` class and finally ended up with `PluginContext` (see [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/qt_gui/html/classqt__gui_1_1plugin__context_1_1PluginContext.html))

Widgets are added through the `context` variable of the dashboard (`context` being of type `PluginContext`) using `add_widget(QWidget)` and specifically for the toolbar - `add_toolbar(QToolBar)`.

---

Originally posted by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) with karma: 299 on 2016-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0